# What is a good way to notify class A of a property change on objects of class B in a list in class A

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime

I have classes A and B as follows:

```
public class A
{
  private List<B> myList;

  public List<B> MyList
  {
      get { return myList; }
      set { myList = value; }
  }

  private bool allComplete;

  public bool AllComplete
  {
    get { return allComplete; }
    set { allComplete = value; }
  }

  public void CalculateAllComplete()
  {
    foreach (B item in MyList)
    {
      if (!item.IsComplete)
      {
        AllComplete = false;
        return;
      }
    }
    AllComplete = true;
  }
}

public class B
{
  private bool isComplete;

  public bool IsComplete
  {
    get { return isComplete; }
    set { isComplete = value; }
  }
}
```

I need to be notified whenever the property `IsComplete` changes on any object of type B in `MyList` in an object of type A. When this happens I will call the `CalculateAllComplete` method to determine if all the items in the list are complete.

What is a good way to do this?

Comment: Best is very subjective and there are lots of ways to handle this. Custom Events, UI in your view or page could trigger it. In fact, if it's important, I'd surface it as a well known pattern rather than relying on `IPropertyNotifyChanged`

Comment: Thank you @WiredPrairie, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface on class B and have the class A instance subscribing for any property changes.

Comment: Actually @Kzrystof suggestion probably is more of what you're looking for.

Comment: What exactly does the class A instance subscribe to? Do I have to loop through all of the items in MyList and add an event listener to PropertyChanged? My concern is that I will end up with 130 instances of A, each having about 10 instances of B in MyList... so I end up with about 1300 instances of B. Is this a performance concern (having so many event listeners)?

Comment: You are right. The class A instance would have to subscribe to the PropertyChanged event of each instance of class B. Performance-wise, I do not see this as an issue. Each instance of class B will only store a reference to its class A's event handler. However, you may have to deal with synchronization issues in the class A's event handler... :)

Answer (score 1):

implement interface IObservable in your class B and subscribe to an instance of B in class A 
take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd990377.aspx